# Pagination - table with too many rows

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to take the number of all the rows from a table in order to calculate how many pages will be there. But the problem is that the table has about 1000 rows and every time when I try to find how many are they, the computer slows down and needs restart.

I only need the number of the rows and nothing else. I tried this:

```
public function countRows()
{
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');

    $q->select('q.username');

    return $q->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

but it seems to be quite slow.

Is there a better and faster way to count the rows? Or maybe another way to do the pagination, but then how to know how many pages will be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function countRows()
{
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');

    $q->select('COUNT(q.username)');

    return $q->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Your query wasn't counting but selecting all rows, which could be very slow.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it's much better! It seems that the rows are above 320 000, not 1000 :D

Answer (score 1):

And if you are calculete COUNT many times, save result of method countRows() in property of this object and return it:

```
public function countRows()
{
    if ($this->countRowsQ === null)
    {
        $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');

        $q->select('COUNT(q.username)');

        $this->countRowsQ = $q->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    }

    return $this->countRowsQ;
}
```